# Audio playback is being paused during navigation instructions

Tags: ios, avfoundation, here-api, avaudiosession

My navigation audio is doing some wierd things. If I am using a music app like spotify, or apple music, during navigation, the audio ducks while the nav instruction is going off.

However, when I have a podcast running from apple podcasts, or overcast, the audio pauses, the navigation plays, and then the audio never starts again. Is this typical for the iOS HERE Maps SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats done in those apps by setting the `AVAudioSession.Mode` to the correct value for the content they're playing.

The `default` option will allow audio ducking like most music apps. `spokenAudio` will pause when something else is playing and then resume afterwards.